# Jquery problem with IE

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i am having problems with Jquery in IE, the code is not working, can any one help me.

http://efm.net.au/component/content/article/54

please check this in IE and FF (or opera, safari, chrome) and select state, and you will see that clubs get loaded but do not show up in IE, but they show up in FF.

Please help its kind of urgent.
thanks

```
    function loadClub()
{




  var st = document.getElementById("State").value;

  if(st != "Select State")
  {
    jQuery("#loaderBox").css("display","block");
//alert(document.getElementById("Club").innerHTML);
//alert($("#State").val());
/*$("div#Club_container").remove();*/

setTimeout('jQuery(".club-drop input").remove();',100);
setTimeout('jQuery("#Club_container").remove();',100);


if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  }

else

  {// code for IE6, IE5

  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()

  {

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

  {/*
$(".state-drop input#State_input").remove();
$("div#State_container").remove();
$(".club-drop input#Club_input").remove();
$("div#Club_container").remove();*/
//setTimeout('$(".state-drop").remove()',500);

if(jQuery("#club1").length > 0)
{

  document.getElementById("club1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   document.getElementById("club2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("club3").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}else{
    document.getElementById("Club").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


}
//jQuery("div.state-drop").css("border","none");
jQuery("div.state-drop span").css("display","none");
     jQuery('.efm-text input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');


    if(jQuery("#club1").length > 0)
{
setTimeout("jQuery('#club1').selectbox()",100);
setTimeout("jQuery('#club2').selectbox()",100);
setTimeout("jQuery('#club3').selectbox()",100);

}else{
setTimeout("jQuery('#Club').selectbox()",100);
    //jQuery('#Club').selectbox();
}

jQuery("#loaderBox").css("display","none");

    }

  }





xmlhttp.open("GET","/club/state-club.php?state="+st,true);

xmlhttp.send();


    }else{
      setTimeout('jQuery(".club-drop input").remove();',100); 
      //jQuery("div.state-drop").css("border","1px solid red");
      jQuery("div.state-drop span").css("display","block");
      jQuery("div.state-drop span").css("color","red");

      jQuery('.efm-text input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        if(jQuery("#club1").length > 0)
        {

         document.getElementById("club1").innerHTML="Select State First";
   document.getElementById("club2").innerHTML="Select State First";
    document.getElementById("club3").innerHTML="Select State First";

    setTimeout("jQuery('#club1').selectbox()",100);
setTimeout("jQuery('#club2').selectbox()",100);
setTimeout("jQuery('#club3').selectbox()",100);

        }else{
       document.getElementById("Club").innerHTML="Select State First";
    setTimeout("jQuery('#Club').selectbox()",100);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: @user612703 - you might try posting the code here that doesn't work. Just posting a link to a website will not get you any answers. BTW: it seems to work fine in IE anyway!

Comment: it is not working for me or my boss, and my boss is about to kill me because it is not working, i have tried a lot of techniques but it is not working on IE (i have IE8)

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery you might as well use it for everything e.g. don't use innerHTML(), ActiveXObject/XMLHttpRequest or onreadystatechange() as jQuery already provides nice cross browser implementations for these.

Comment: i was not able to get good understanding of .ajax() method of jquery thats whay i choose the old fashioned ajax

Comment: $.get or $.getJSON are simplified versions of  $.ajax.

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem but your response looks like this:
"<br /><option value='Brisbane South'>Brisbane South</option><br /><option value='Herston'>Herston</option><br /><option value='Noosa'>Noosa</option>"

Point 1. You should not include <br/> tags as I am not sure if they are valid inside a <select/>, IE might not be working because of this.
Point 2. You should not be returning html. You should return basic objects and build your select options from that.

Comment: @row1 - returning HTML is a valid technique. It's not as flexible as returning XML or JSON, but it's a perfectly valid way of doing things. Your first point about not including the `<br />` tags is spot on, though.

Comment: i have not included it with out purpose, i was just putting it there in an effort to correct it, i read it some where on the net, i tried, and it did not work and i removed it, but i think you also visited at the same time i did. now <br> is not there but problem continue to exist

Answer (score 1):

1 - Upgrade to the latest version of jQuery. I have never faced any cross browser issues with jQUery.

2 - Replace your ajax code with jQuery code.

E.g -

```
     $.post("/someapp/login.do",$("#loginForm").serialize(), function(data) {
                    // Callback code
        $('#loginDiv').html(data);
    });
```

Comment: perhaps it is not a problem with jquery, this is a problem with following line
jQuery('#Club').selectbox();

this line is used to refresh the rsform to give better look, i am working with rsform in joomla